# Google Storage : how to check if a bucket exists

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Using GoLang SDK for google cloud storage.... Cannot find a method to check if a bucket exists.

```
func (c *Client) Bucket(name string) *BucketHandle
```

Bucket returns a BucketHandle even if bucket does not exist.

So, how can I check if the bucket exists? I do not want to create the bucket if it does not exist, so cannot take the route of trying to create a bucket and handle errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by using the [Attrs function](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage#BucketHandle.Attrs) :

```
bucket := client.Bucket(bucketName)
exists,err := bucket.Attrs(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Message: %v",err)
}
fmt.Println(exists)
```

Since `err`, prints `Message: storage: bucket doesn't exist`.

In case you consider that having a function that directly mentions if a bucket exists or not would be useful, I suggest filling a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=1162894) to the Cloud Storage engineering team to consider having it on further releases.

Answer (score 0):

you can `func (c *Client) Buckets(ctx context.Context, projectID string) *BucketIterator` to iterate over the existing buckets and check if it exists.

Comment: That looks more like a brute force approach. Is there no API which would take a bucket name and return if it exists?

Comment: Yeah, if you have hundreds of buckets... that's probably not a good idea.